# ensureIndexIsVisible(int) is not working

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, listselectionlistener

I am very new to Java, and am using Netbeans. I have made a JList to use as a recept, it is contained within a jScrollPane. As I add items to the jList, I want it to stick to the bottom, to scroll with the last item on the list. I've tried to use `ensureIndexIsVisible(int)` but it never seems to have any effect at all.

I've declared the DLM...

```
public class ShoppingCart extends javax.swing.JFrame {

DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
```

And am using this to populate the list....

```
private void PrintToReceipt(){

    JList Receipt = new JList( dlm );

    dlm.addElement(ItemQuantity + "@ " + Money.format(ItemPrice) + " * " + TaxRate.format(ItemTax) + "% = " + Money.format(ItemTotal));

    Receipt.ensureIndexIsVisible(Receipt.getSelectedIndex());

}
```

I have also tried variations of `getSelectedIndex`, but simply putting my variable to keep track of how many items I have added, nothing works. When i add more then can be seen in the viewport, it simple keeps adding them, but the scrollbar stays at the top.
Can anyone give me any idea what else I can try?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 4):

Check what's the selected index value. Also try to wrap the ensureIndexIsVisible in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`

Comment: and with ListSelectionListener

Answer (score 3):

there are two ways:

by wrapping `ensureIndexIsVisible` to the `invokeLater` (as `@Stas` mentioned +1)

or

use `ListSelectionListener` directly, for example

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class ListOneItem extends JFrame implements ListSelectionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ListOneItem() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        String[] numbers = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"};
        final JList list = new JList(numbers);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(1);
        list.addListSelectionListener(this);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        add(scrollPane);
        Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                list.setSelectedIndex(3);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
    }

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(final ListSelectionEvent e) {
        JList list = (JList) e.getSource();
        list.ensureIndexIsVisible(list.getSelectedIndex());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ListOneItem frame = new ListOneItem();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doRun);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm ... nothing much wrong with the example (except not guarding against isValueAdjusting) but has not much to do with the add/ensure _added_ row is visible ...

Comment: @kleopatra correct comment, please really doesn't make me any sense to solve that in thread this nature,